# Ajax variable not working in php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Here I am getting the value from the HTML page through JavaScript, accessing that value from ajax and passing that value to PHP page.

The PHP page should delete from the table using that ajax value but the PHP is not getting that ajax value...

Here is what I have tried:

### JavaScript

```
var str;
function getResults(a) 
{
       str = a;
}

function showUser() {

    if(str=="") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getmovie.php?q="+str,true);
    alert(str);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

### PHP

```
<?php
$q = strtolower(trim($_GET["q"]));
try 
{
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=theaterdb;host=localhost','tiger','tiger');
}
catch (PDOException $e) 
{
echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
$sql = 'DELETE FROM movie WHERE LOWER(movie_name) = :q';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindValue(':q', $q);
$sth->execute();
$dbh = null;
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($q);` ?

Comment: you can echoing your delete query and check it.

Comment: @VIVEK-MDU I tried that but it is not printing any value.

Comment: In your browser's "Net" tab, do you see the GET request being made with the correct parameters?

Comment: try to just echo the variable you get in php page ,lets see what response you are getting back.

Answer (score 1):

This, code is looking fine, try to `echo` after `delete operation` like,

```
    .......
    ......
    if(!$q)  {// check the movie name,  if empty then return;
       echo 'Movie name is empty';
       return;
    }
    $sql = 'DELETE FROM movie WHERE LOWER(movie_name) = :q';
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->bindValue(':q', $q);
    if($sth->execute())  $msg=$q.' deleted successfully.';
    else $msg=$q.' not deleted.';
    $dbh = null;
    echo $msg;
    return;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you placed the code Rohan has give you right after the catch clause

```
$q = strtolower(trim($_GET["q"]));
$q = strtolower(trim($_GET["q"]));
try 
{
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=your_database;host=localhost','your_user','your_password');
}
catch (PDOException $e) 
{
echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
if(!$q)  {// check the movie name,  if empty then return;
   echo 'Movie name is empty';
   return;
}
$sql = 'DELETE FROM movie WHERE LOWER(movie_name) = :q';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindValue(':q', $q);
if($sth->execute())  $msg=$q.' deleted successfully.';
else $msg=$q.' not deleted.';
$dbh = null;
echo $msg;
return;
?>
```